# I found an error while declaring a list in dart programmiong language on dart pad

Tags: dart, error-handling

`error : The class 'List' doesn't have an unnamed constructor.`

this error appear while declaring a list.

following was line of code where error seems to be occured:

```
var divisor = new List(100);
```

this error was displayed on dart pad